# Check string for illegal characters in path

Tags: android

Users can choose a own downloadpath for their data and i want the 'path' or 'directory' string to be checked on illegal characters (!@#$%^&*, etc) and if possible replace them.

Can somebody help pls?
Thank you in advance.

```
public void onDownloadLocationChanged(final String newLocation) {
   //
     final String original = settings.getDownloadsLocation();
     //
      if (!newLocation.equals(original)) {
       //
         if (new File (newLocation).isDirectory() && (new File(newLocation).exists())) {
       // DoSomething
   }}
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and what didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this by using the `replaceAll` String method. For example, if you wanted to remove the "@" character from your string, you could do the following:

`original.replaceAll("[\\@]", "");`

The call above will replace all of the occurences of "@" within the string with a "", which essentially means that the character was deleted. Furthermore, you can add any character you wish to remove to the call above. If you wish to use a different replacement for each bad character, then you would need to consider multiple `replaceAll` statements, but if you simply want to remove illegal characters from your string then this is the way to go.

Comment: @Willes,
thx, so for mutiple illegal characters i would need several replaceAll commands?
Any easier solution?

Comment: Not quite. If you simply wish to remove all illegal characters from a string and replace them with "", which essentially deletes the character, then you could do so with one statement. You could remove all of the characters that you mentioned in your question (!@#$%^&*) by simply calling the following: `original.replaceAll("[!@#$%^&*]","");`.

Comment: @Willes
Thx that`s what i wanted to know.

Comment: @Willes
Hi Willes 
a question is there any way i can avoid that the user creates directories like /storage/emulated/0/home///
It should be a valid one like /storage/emulated/0/home/

Thx again